# Texture Painting object stays black

Tags: texture-painting

I'm trying to texture paint a donut for a beginner's blender tutorial but for some reason the donut stays black when I try and paint. I've made a texture so I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

https://gofile.io/d/Qy2O5F

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Because you have created a *Texture* brush, and it was black, you need to close it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add an attribute node and set the name as your vertex colors

Comment: I tried that and am still having the same issue.

Comment: sometimes when you try that you mess with the names , go to the object data and look for vertext colors

Comment: Okay figured it out. IDK why but I had to delete the brush and make a new one. Literally the only change. thank you for your help!